# All AUR packages..after builded by makepkg .. necessarily create an *.pkg.tar.xz file?

Tags: archlinux

Well .. this question came from another one closed question that i posted here. I installed android using yaourt.. and that was ok.. it worked fine.

But, before that i was trying doing manually.. using makepkg. But it seems that it did not create any package named *.pkg.tar.xz .

After a search.. and some question for my friends.. they told me that maybe the make process had problems and, it had some silent problem that not created the *.pkg.tar.xz.
So.. what do you think.. all AUR packages necessarily create *.pkg.tar.xz file and it was a problem when i was trying to build. Or has certain packages , as android , that do not create such *.pkg.tar.xz files?

Comment: Could you show us the output from yaourt build? Sounds like it's likely a build problem.

Answer (score 1):

An AUR package is a `PKGBUILD` file with instructions to `makepkg` to build a package (which is a .pkg.tar.xz file), so yes, unless there is any error on the build process, all AUR packages create a .pkg.tar.xz file.

You could try downloading the PKGBUILD file and running the `makepkg -si` manually to check any build error. Here's an example to build and install the android-sdk package, adjust accordingly to your desired package. This should create a android-sdk-*-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz file.

```
cd $(mktemp -d)
wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/an/android-sdk/android-sdk.tar.gz
tar xzvf android-sdk.tar.gz
cd android-sdk/
makepkg -si
```

Used arguments to makepkg:

```
-s, --syncdeps   Install missing dependencies with pacman
-i, --install    Install package after successful build
```